# Как сделать так, что бы игра выглядела одинакова с разными разрешениями?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

Пишу игру на JS используя canvas API. Как сделать так, что бы игра выглядела одинакова на экранах с другим разрешением? Например, у меня есть фотография платформы 20х20 px. Допустим, что разрешение моего экрана - 1920×1080 px. Я сделал все так, что бы оно выглядело нормально на моем экране. Как адаптировать это под другое разрешение?

Comment: Зависит от того, что именно вы подразумеваете под словами "одинакова" и "нормально"

Comment: По возможности используйте векторную графику. | Растровые изображения заранее сделайте нескольких разрешений и динамически выбирайте наиболее подходящее.